# Capturing just "abc-def-ghi" in the string "utm_campaign=abc-def-ghi"

Tags: r, regex, string

I am new to REGEX. As per title, I would like to capture `abc-def-ghi` in the string `utm_campaign=abc-def-ghi`. The string is usually embedded in an url. Using the following pattern `(utm_campaign=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` I can match the entire string, but I really just want the second part of the string, which is `abc-def-ghi`. Is there an efficient way to do this in regex? Preferable language for this question is R.

Comment: Put the parentheses around the part you want to capture, not around the whole thing.

Comment: `(?<=utm_campaign=)[\w-]+` and set `perl=T`

Comment: @ctwheels thanks that does solve this!

Comment: @Daniel give me a minute to post as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/LsDeL3/1)

```
(?<=utm_campaign=)[\w-]+
```

- `(?<=utm_campaign=)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches `utm_campaign=` literally
- `[\w-]+` Match any word character (`a-zA-Z0-9_`) or hyphen character one or more times

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K/r/v0LBRldBqbQkNz45MbcgMTM9zzYxKVk3JTVNNz0jU4krFyRflJqeWlFQpKGkYW9ji6JWMzomplw3VltJR6FCR6EgtSjHNiQo1FWTC6glN7EkOSO1WAMokav5/z8A)

```
x <- "utm_campaign=abc-def-ghi"
m <- regexpr("(?<=utm_campaign=)[\\w-]+", x, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(x, m)
```

Result: `abc-def-ghi`

Comment: You'd better use the whole `TRUE` rather than `T` because `T` may be re-assigned a value earlier in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Another option: `gsub`

```
> string <- "utm_campaign=abc-def-ghi"
> gsub(".*=(\\w*)", "\\1", string)
[1] "abc-def-ghi"
```